# How to test custom validation rules in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, validation, unit-testing, tdd, laravel-5

I created a custom validation rule in Laravel, extending it in the `register()` method of a service provider, and I'd like to test it, but don't know how.

I took a look at [Laravel framework's validation tests](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/tests/Validation/ValidationValidatorTest.php), but I couldn't understand the purpose of the `getTranslator()` and `getRealTranslator()` methods.

Could someone give me a hint on how to test Laravel's custom validation rules?

**EDIT**

That's what I did:

Created a `ValidatorServiceProvider` as follows:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ValidatorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
    * Bootstrap the application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app['validator']->extend('greater_than', function($attr, $val, $params)
        {
            return false;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

Also added it to the providers array and issued `composer dump-autoload -o`.

Added the following to `tests\CustomValidationRulesTest.php`:

```
<?php

use Mockery as m;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomValidationRulesTest extends TestCase {

    public function tearDown()
    {
        m::close();
    }

    public function testValidateGreaterThan()
    {
        $trans = $this->getTranslator();

        $rules = [
            'field2' => 'greater_than:field1'
        ];

        $data = [
            'field1' => 1,
            'field2' => 2
        ];

        $v = new Validator($trans, $data, $rules);
        $this->assertTrue($v->passes());
    }

    protected function getTranslator()
    {
        return m::mock('Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface');
    }

    protected function getRealTranslator()
    {
        $trans = new Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator('en', new Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector);
        $trans->addLoader('array', new Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\ArrayLoader);
        return $trans;
    }

}
```

Running PHPUnit gives me the following:

```
PHPUnit 4.6.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from /home/ubuntu/workspace/phpunit.xml

E.

Time: 248 ms, Memory: 14.75Mb

There was 1 error:

1) CustomValidationRulesTest::testValidateGreaterThan
BadMethodCallException: Method [validateGreaterThan] does not exist.

/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:2615
/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:372
/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:372
/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:325
/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/CustomValidationRulesTest.php:27
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand a bit more the `Container` or `IoC` and how the `Validator` is registered there.

Laravel registers an instance of `Illuminate\Validation\Factory` as `validator`. So if you check the `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator`, you find that it resolves to the `Factory`. When you extend the validator, you are in fact adding an extension in the `Factory`. Now, calling `Validator::make()` calls the `Factory` which has the extensions and it creates the `Validator` with the extensions, while instantiating a new `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` won't be able to resolve the extentions from the `Factory`.

You should not instantiate a new `Validator`, but use `app('validator')->make()`.

Answer (score 2):

Take it:

```
protected function getRealTranslator()
    {
        $loader = new \Illuminate\Translation\ArrayLoader;
        $translator = new \Illuminate\Translation\Translator($loader, 'ja');
        return $translator;
    }
```